# Increase scrollbar height automatically

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I make the scrollbar on a page always visible with:

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

On the other hand, I also want the scrollbar height increase automatically when opening a modal dialog that is longer than the page. However, the scrollbar height does not increase automatically. If I set **overflow-y: auto;** this makes the scrollbar hidden for the initial state that I do not like. Any idea to fix it?

Comment: Snippet would be quite helpful, especially when your code isn't that really complicated.

Answer (score 0):

[Bootstrap's modal](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#live-demo) does an excellent job of this by hiding body overflow and using a fixed overlay.

```
body.modal-open{overflow:hidden}
/* this is the overlay */
.modal{position:fixed;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;}
.modal .modal-dialog{/* taller than window */}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I cannot make it to work. On the other hand, maybe I could not explain the problem, my problem is that: when opening the modal, the scrollbar of the body is disabled and cannot navigate on the body. I do not want modal scrollbar and just want to use the scrollbar of body when modal is opened. Any idea?

Comment: You should set up a jsfiddle or codepen so we can see what you're doing.